# Intersection of $D(a), D(b) $ and $d\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Reading Burton's Elementary Number Theory, I try to make my ideas clear by attempting at drawing a Venn diagram involving the sets " divisors of number $a$" , " divisors of number $b$", " set of all numbers of the form  $ ax+by$ ( with $x,y \in \mathbb Z$)".

---

Let $a, b$ be integers not both equal to $0$.

By $D(a)$ I mean the set of all divisors of number $a$, by $D(b)$ I mean the set of all divisors of number $b$, by $ d\mathbb Z$ I mean the set of all multiples of $d = \text{gcd}(a,b)$.

It can be shown that $d\mathbb Z = \{ax+by | x,y \in \mathbb Z \}$.

My question is : is it necessarily the case that $d\mathbb Z \cap D(a) = d$ and that $ d\mathbb Z \cap D(b) = d$ , or ***could a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ bring us back ( so to say) in one of the sets $D(a)$ or $D(b)$  at a "point" different from number $d$?***.

Visually, in terms of Venn diagrams, is a "third" dimension required to draw the set $d\mathbb Z$ making sure this set never intersects $D(a)$ nor $D(b)$, except at "point" $d= gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Try some examples with small numbers. E.g. $a=2,b=3,d=1$.